# Confluence: defining constants or default values on templates

Tags: confluence

I am using Confluence 5.10.8. Is it possible to define constants on templates? Let's say I have a constant 001.000.000 which I have to mention at several places in my template. Is it possible to give it a name, e.g. `initialVersion` and reference that instead?

Or alternatively: Is it possible to give template variables default values?

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible to set default value to template variable.